# how to reduce Resharper's indentation with parenthesis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

this is what I have currently:

```
return Helper(
              topResults: topResults,
              pick: baseResults => (from result in baseResults
                                    where result.MatchPoint == matchPoint
                                    select result.Torque).First());
```

but, I'd would like the following:

```
return Helper(
   topResults: topResults,
   pick: baseResults => (
       from result in baseResults
       where result.MatchPoint == matchPoint
       select result.Torque).First());
```

I've been playing around with the resharper formatting settings, and I just can't seem to quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it under

`RESHARPER -> OPTIONS -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other`

I had to uncheck the `Align Multiline Constructs -> Call arguments` box.